# "compass watch" compiles one file and not another

Tags: css, ruby, sass, rubygems, compass

I have a set of SASS files and I use Compass as my pre-processor. I run `compass watch` in the MacOSX Terminal.

My files are structured so that all of my code gets compiled twice... once with media queries in `mq.css` and once without in `no-mq.css`. The non-media query code is meant for IE8 and browsers that won't recognize media queries.

When I make a change to any of my files, my `mq.css` gets compiled but very seldom does the `no-mq.css`. If I `compass clean` and then manually `compass compile` they both will. If I run only `compass compile` without a clean first, only the `mq.css` compiles. I can run `watch` all day and my `mq.css` will continue to get compiled.

I've upgraded, downgraded, and generally played with combinations of SASS and Compass. I am not using Susy or another SASS-related library. I do have SASS maps turned on.

My SCSS starter package can be reviewed here: https://github.com/jhogue/scss-scaffold in case I am missing something in `config.rb` or `/sass/framework/_config.scss`.

My gems are as follows:

- compass (1.0.3)
- compass-core (1.0.3)
- compass-import-once (1.0.5, 1.0.4)
- css_parser (1.3.5)
- fssm (0.2.10)
- libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
- listen (1.1.6, 0.7.3)
- sass (3.4.7)

Its not as critical as it is annoying, and I'd like to know if anyone else has encountered this or a similar issue.

Comment: I face the exact same problem after I upgraded to windows 10 yesterday and reinstalled a clean ruby with only compass added up to now. So it's pretty much clean. Everything was working before and now, only the first of my 10 css-files in this project (different color themes of the otherwise same css) gets compiled. If I usw clean and compile it works, without clean it doesn't. Have you ever figured out what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem several times in the past, and have found it often occurs when I have partials inside of subdirectories.  Calling `add_import_path` in the config.rb file for each subdirectory has usually fixed it:

```
// config.rb
add_import_path "sass/framework"
```

Of course a `compass clean` before watching/compiling is in order as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying it on a few projects but it doesn't seem to be helping. I wonder if I have the paths wrong. I am assuming that it should be relative to the location of the config file, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, its relative to the `config.rb` file. The only thing I can think of is to be sure you're calling it as a function not assigning it to a variable (no `=` sign)

Comment: Still no resolution that fixes this. I recently have started to have `watch` just sit there and silently fail even though I am saving changes, so I think I need to throw out a bunch of my gems and start over with new installs.